sharepoint Rows for projects
I have columns that each represent something. I am trying to have a title with different task underneath, the only issue that I come across is that when I add to the task it shows on one row. I am trying to have power automate create different rows for one project each time one is created.

Your question is not clear. What does that have to do with SharePoint Designer if you are using Power Automate? It looks to me that you are not really understanding the words for the concepts you are describing.
